Why does clicking on the menu item cause jumping instead of smooth scrolling in Lenis and Vue.js?
I'm having an issue with smooth scrolling to a section of the page when clicking on a menu item. I'm using the Lenis library in conjunction with Vue.js to enable smooth scrolling on my website. However, instead of smoothly scrolling to the target section, the page jumps to the destination section.
Below is the code from my application:
<template>
  <div
    class="sticky left-0 top-0 z-50 w-full border-b-2 border-[#2e2e32] bg-[#141414] shadow-2xl"
  >
    <div
      class="container relative mx-auto flex h-20 items-center justify-between px-3 lg:justify-between"
    >
      <div class="hidden w-1/3 lg:block"></div>
      <a
        href="#"
        class="w-1/3 text-start font-mono text-xl font-semibold lg:text-center"
      >
        ...
      </a>
      <nav
        class="hidden w-1/3 items-center justify-end gap-6 bg-gradient-to-r from-fuchsia-400 to-pink-600 bg-clip-text text-lg font-semibold text-transparent lg:flex"
      >
        <a href="#stack" onclick="lenis.scrollTo('#stack')">Stack</a>
        <a href="#projects" onclick="lenis.scrollTo('#projects')">Projects</a>
        <a href="#contact" onclick="lenis.scrollTo('#contact')"> Let's Talk </a>
      </nav>

      <div
        class="relative h-5 w-9 cursor-pointer lg:hidden"
        @click="isActive = !isActive"
      >
        <span class="absolute right-1 top-2 h-0.5 w-8 bg-white"></span>
        <span
          class="absolute right-1 top-3 h-0.5 bg-white transition-all"
          :class="isActive ? 'w-5' : 'w-8'"
        ></span>
      </div>

      <div
        class="absolute right-2 top-24 flex flex-col gap-y-4 opacity-0 transition-all duration-300"
        :class="{
          'opacity-100': isActive,
          invisible: !isActive,
          '-translate-y-1': isActive,
        }"
      >
        <div
          class="flex h-40 w-72 flex-col justify-center rounded-lg bg-white px-3 py-4 font-mono font-bold uppercase text-black shadow-xl"
        >
          <a
            @click="deactive"
            href="#stack"
            onclick="lenis.scrollTo('#stack')"
            class="group relative h-full w-full"
            ><div
              class="absolute left-0 top-0 h-full w-full scale-[.85] rounded-[6rem] bg-sky-200 opacity-0 transition duration-300 ease-in-out group-hover:scale-100 group-hover:opacity-100"
            ></div>
            <div
              class="absolute left-0 top-0 z-20 flex h-full w-full items-center justify-between px-3 py-4"
            >
              <h1>stack</h1>
              <div class="arrow">
                <i class="bx bx-right-arrow-alt"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a
            @click="deactive"
            href="#projects"
            onclick="lenis.scrollTo('#projects')"
            class="group relative h-full w-full"
            ><div
              class="absolute left-0 top-0 h-full w-full scale-[.85] rounded-[6rem] bg-sky-200 opacity-0 transition duration-300 ease-in-out group-hover:scale-100 group-hover:opacity-100"
            ></div>
            <div
              class="absolute left-0 top-0 z-20 flex h-full w-full items-center justify-between px-3 py-4"
            >
              <h1>projects</h1>
              <div class="arrow">
                <i class="bx bx-right-arrow-alt"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <a
          @click="deactive"
          href="#contact"
          onclick="lenis.scrollTo('#contact')"
          class="flex h-24 w-72 items-center justify-between rounded-lg bg-white bg-gradient-to-r from-[#f6d5f7] to-[#fbe9d7] px-6 py-8 font-mono font-bold uppercase text-black shadow-xl"
        >
          <h1>Contact</h1>
          <div class="flex -rotate-45 items-center justify-center text-xl">
            <i class="bx bx-right-arrow-alt"></i>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
const isActive = ref(false);

function deactive() {
  isActive.value = false;
}
</script>


and app.vue
import { onMounted } from "vue";
import Lenis from "@studio-freight/lenis";
import Header from "./components/Header/Header.vue";
import Initial from "./components/InitialSection/Initial.vue";
import Stack from "./components/StackSection/Stack.vue";
import Contact from "./components/Contact/Contact.vue";
import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer.vue";
import Projects from "./components/ProjectsSection/Projects.vue";

onMounted(() => {
  const lenis = new Lenis();

  function raf(time) {
    lenis.raf(time);
    requestAnimationFrame(raf);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(raf);
});
</script>

<template>
  <Header />
  <Initial />
  <Stack />
  <Projects />
  <Contact />
  <Footer />
</template>

I know that when I use Lenis' CDN in HTML, the smooth transition works normally without skipping. I also tried to get help from chatgpt, but nothing helped.
